# read /dev/ttyUSB0 failed?

Tags: tty, gps

I have a GPS device connected to /dev/ttyUSB0 I wrote a simple code to read data from it but the reading always fails I have no idea where the problem is this is my code could you please help me :).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

using namespace std;
int read_port(void) 
{
int fd;
fd = open("dev/ttyUSB0" , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd ==-1) 
{
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");

}

   char buffer[32];
    int n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
        fputs("read failed!\n", stderr);
    return (fd);
}

int main()
{
     read_port();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume cuz you are missing a `/` in front of `dev`?

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0" , O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
```

---

If I was you I would make a variable for this

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

That way the `open` and the `error` can show the same file name. Saves confusion.